# Check that array only contains string objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a more concise way than the below to check if an array only contains String class objects?

```
a = ['one','twon','three']  # => ["one", "twon", "three"]

b = ['one','twon', 1 ]  # => ["one", "twon", 1]

c = ['one','twon', {one: 1} ]  # => ["one", "twon", {:one=>1}]

def contains_only_string_class(object)
  uniq_a= object.map{ |i| i.class }.uniq          # => [String], [String, Integer], [String, Hash]
  uniq_a.include?(String) & (uniq_a.length == 1)  # => true,     false,             false
end                                               # => :contains_only_string_class

contains_only_string_class(a)  # => true
contains_only_string_class(b)  # => false
contains_only_string_class(c)  # => false
```

Comment: If this were [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) I'd suggest `arr==arr.grep(String)`.

Answer (score 5):

What about using [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```
def contains_only_string_class(collection)
  collection.all? { |obj| obj.is_a?(String) }
end
```

Comment: If you use one of the newer Ruby versions you could also provide a pattern: `collection.all?(String)`